# Integer gets automatically set to 0 C#

Tags: c#, console, int

I am doing an exercise on making a small console program which shows how fast a car is moving and a function to make it go either faster or slower.

So here is my class called car, it contains a constructor.
There is a get and set accessor for the *private int speed*.
There are 2 methods called accelerate and break.

```
class car
{
    private int speed;

    public car (int initialSpeed) //initializes car speed
    {
        Speed = initialSpeed;
    }


    public void accelerate() //increase Speed
    {
        Speed = Speed + 10;
    }


    public void brake() //decrease Speed
    {
        Speed = Speed - 10;
    }


    public int Speed //access private int speed
    {
        get { return speed; }
        set { speed = Speed; }
    }


}
```

Now here is the problem:

```
class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Car = new car(5);
        Console.WriteLine(Car.Speed);

    }
}
```

When I run the program the console just displays 0 even though initialized with 5. Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it does compile for me

Comment: `Speed` is not `speed` (identifiers are case sensitive)

Comment: You should follow [.NET capitalization conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx). So classes should be pascal-case which means they start with an uppercase letter whereas local variables should start with a lowercase letter. Otherwise it's difficult to read your code.

Comment: `set { speed = Speed; }` should be `set { speed = value; }`

Comment: Or, alternatively `public int Speed { get; set; }`, and get rid of the `speed` field altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `Speed` property is the problem. Here's the code:

```
public int Speed //access private int speed
{
    get { return speed; }
    set { speed = Speed; }
}
```

The getter is fine - it returns the value of the private variable.

The setter, however, sets the value of variable to the result of evaluating the getter - ignoring the value passed into the setter entirely (available via the `value` variable). It should be:

```
public int Speed
{
    get { return speed; }
    set { speed = value; }
}
```

Or better yet, use an [automatically implemented property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb384054.aspx) - remove the `speed` field, and just have:

```
public int Speed { get; set; }
```

At the same time, I'd suggest learning about compound assignment operators and .NET naming conventions. If you're using C# 6 you can also use expression-bodied members, leaving a really small amount of code:

```
class Car
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }

    public Car(int initialSpeed)
    {
        Speed = initialSpeed;
    }    

    public void Accelerate() => Speed += 10;   
    public void Brake() => Speed -= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this code:

```
public int Speed //access private int speed
{
    get { return speed; }
    set { speed = Speed; }
}
```

to

```
public int Speed //access private int speed
{
    get { return speed; }
    set { speed = value; }
}
```

In C# properties, the setter uses the `value` keyword to set values to the underlying field.

Answer (score 1):

Your `set` assessor should be

```
set { speed = value; }
```

So your property definition becomes

```
public int Speed //access private int speed
{
    get { return speed; }
    set { speed = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the set, change this

```
    set { speed = Speed; }
```

for this

```
    set { speed = value; }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@Jay is correct but the preferred syntax in this case is

```
public int Speed { get; set;}
```

and remove

```
private int speed;
```

Let the compiler handle the member details for you since you are not running any actual logic in the get/set properties­­­­